# cuda gdb debugging information for dynamically compiled kernels

Tags: gdb, cuda

I'm dynamically compiling kernels for cuda. Is there some way to add debugging information to the binary that is dynamically generated from the run-time generated assembly string?
I want to use cuda-gdb on it.

Thanks.

PS Can someone please create a tag cuda-gdb?

Comment: second. i've wanted cuda-gdb a few times, too.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are creating a .cubin file from a .cu file using nvcc, and later using cuModuleLoad, cuLaunchGrid and friends to actually launch your kernel. In that case, you can pass "-G" to nvcc when converting .cu to .cubin. Then, you can run your program under cuda-gdb and place a breakpoint in the kernel and that breakpoint should be triggered.